# How do you calculate eigenvector/value of a non-square matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix-decomposition

I have been wanting to calculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors for a non-square matrix and I know that `svd` method is used.

But, given my poor background, I don't understand how to figure out eigenvalues and eigenvectors from the `u`, `d` and `v` matrices.

Comment: You are not precise terminologically. Eigenvalues/vectors that you imply here are _not_ a characteristic of non-square matrix X, they are property of square matrix X'X.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the man page, `svd` returns a list with the following elements:

> - d: a vector containing the singular values of x, of length min(n, p).
> - u: a matrix whose columns contain the left singular vectors of x, present if nu 0. Dimension c(n, nu).
> - v: a matrix whose columns contain the right singular vectors of x, present if nv 0. Dimension c(p, nv).

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) describes the relation between Eigendecomposition and SVD as follows: Given the SVD of $M$

$$M = U \; \Sigma \; V^*,$$

then

> - The left singular vectors of $M$ are eigenvectors of $MM^*$.
> - The right singular vectors of $M$ are eigenvectors of $M^*M$.
> - The non-zero singular values of $\Sigma$ are the square roots of the non-zero eigenvalues of $M^*M$ or $MM^*$.

Does that help answer your question on how to identify the results returned by `svd`?